# Evaluate the integral $\int_{\large \frac13}^3\frac{\sin^{-1}\frac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}xdx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I found the following integral on the net.
$$\int_{\frac13}^3\frac{\sin^{-1}\frac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}x\ dx$$
My approach was putting $x=\tan\theta$, after which the integral reduces to $\theta\cot\theta$. Then what should I do?

I got stuck while applying integration by parts because $\int{\theta\cot\theta}=\theta\int\cot\theta-\int\int\cot\theta$. How should I find the integral of $\int\ln\sin x$ which occurs in the second term?

Comment: You forgot that $dx = \sec^2{\theta} d\theta$.  Thus the integrand is $2 \theta/\sin{(2 \theta)}$.

Comment: @RonGordon Oh right.Thanks

Comment: @RonGordon But even $2xcosec(2x)$ is'nt easy to integrate ...can you suggest something?

Comment: @OlivierOloa's solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, one may observe that
$$
\left(\arcsin\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)'=\frac1{1+x^2}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}, \tag1
$$ giving 
$$
\arcsin\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\arctan x, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}, \tag2
$$
then integrating by parts, one gets
$$
\begin{align}
I:=\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{\arcsin\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}x\:dx &=\left[\ln x\frac{}{} \arctan x\right]_{1/3}^3-\int_{1/3}^3\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\: dx
\\\\&=\left[\ln x\frac{}{} \arctan x\right]_{1/3}^3-0
\\\\&=\ln 3\cdot \arctan 3+\ln 3\cdot \arctan \frac13
\end{align}
$$ then, using $\arctan x+ \arctan \dfrac1x=\dfrac{\pi}2$, $x>0$,

> $$
> \int_{1/3}^3 \frac{\arcsin\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}x\:dx=\frac{\pi}2 \: \ln 3.
> $$

*Remark*. By the change of variable $u=\dfrac1x$, $du=-\dfrac{dx}{x^2}$, we have noticed that
$$
\int_{1/3}^3\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\: dx=-\int_{1/3}^3\frac{\ln u}{1+u^2}\: du=0.
$$

Comment: May be, you could precise why the last integral is $0$. Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Edited. Thanks!